# ansible: specifying directory path using variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

My Task: Generate jinja2 templates

Challenge: i wanted to make my playbook/roles independent, and usable in any server irrespective of their HOME directory name, So i have stored the $HOME path into a variable and use that directory location variable to access jinja2 source files.. $HOME stored variable works fine in all tasks, but i am getting error while i use it inside `template` module"

my role structure..

```
roles/
└── my_role
    ├── defaults
    │   ├── main
    │   │   └── input.yml
    │   └── main.yml
    ├── files
    │   ├── conf
    │   │   └── test.yml
    ├── handlers
    │   └── main.yml
    ├── meta
    │   └── main.yml
    ├── README.md
    ├── tasks
    │   ├── data-input.yml
    │   ├── main.yml
    ├── templates
    │   ├── DIR1
    │   │   ├── PATH1
    │   │   │   ├── file1
    ├── tests
    │   ├── inventory
    │   └── test.yml
    └── vars
        ├── main
        │   └── input.yml
        └── main.yml
```

and my task for generating jinja2 templates..

```
---
  - include_vars: vars/main/input.yml

  - name: Generate templates
    template:
        src: {{ home }}/roles/my_role/templates/DIR1/PATH1/file1
        dest: {{ home }}/roles/my_role/templates/DIR1/PATH1/file2
```

`{{ home }}` stands for `/home/ansible` that i have stored it to name `home` using $HOME linux variable.

**Getting Error:**

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key

The error appears to be in '/home/ansible/roles/my_role/tasks/data_input.yml': line 6, column 24, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

    template:
        src: {{ home }}/roles/my_role/templates/DIR1/PATH1/file1
                       ^ here
```

i have even tried `templates/DIR1/PATH1/file1` directory only. but no luck. 
It works fine when i specify full directory path `/home/ansible/roles/my_role/templates/DIR1/PATH1/file1` in both `src` and `dest`..

please help.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [env](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/env.html#env-read-the-value-of-environment-variables) plugin to "read the value of environment variables". For example

```
- set_fact:
    my_home: "{{ lookup('env','HOME') }}"
- template:
    src: "{{ my_home }}/roles/my_role/templates/DIR1/PATH1/file1"
```

---

Notes

1) It's possible to use [role_path](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) special variable

> *"The path to the dir of the currently running role"*

For example

```
src: '{{ role_path }}/templates/DIR1/PATH1/file1'
```

2) But, this shouldn't be necessary because of [The magic of ‘local’ paths](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbook_pathing.html#the-magic-of-local-paths)

> *"Relative paths get attempted first with a ‘files|templates|vars’ appended (if not already present), depending on the action being taken, ‘files’ is the default. (i.e include_vars will use vars/). The paths will be searched from most specific to most general (i.e role before play).|*

Hence, the path below show work by default

```
src: 'DIR1/PATH1/file1'
```

---

For example the role

```
$ tree roles/test14/
roles/test14/
├── defaults
│   └── main.yml
├── files
├── handlers
│   └── main.yml
├── meta
│   └── main.yml
├── README.md
├── tasks
│   └── main.yml
├── templates
│   └── DIR1
│       └── PATH1
│           └── file1
├── tests
│   ├── inventory
│   └── test.yml
└── vars
    └── main.yml

$ cat roles/test14/tasks/main.yml 
- template:
    src: 'DIR1/PATH1/file1'
    dest: '/scratch/tmp/test14'

$ cat roles/test14/templates/DIR1/PATH1/file1 
{{ inventory_hostname }}
```

with the playbook

```
$ cat test14.yml
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - test14
```

works as expected

> PLAY RECAP
>   localhost: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

```
$ cat /scratch/tmp/test14 
localhost
```

Comment: thanks a lot.... first option {{ role_path }} worked well for me.. i have even tried second option i.e., src: 'DIR1/PATH1/file1' but i got error saying that directory does not exists..

Comment: You're welcome. The second option works for me. I've added an example.

Answer (score 4):

**Rule**: In an ansible yaml files (included, in roles, your playbook....), [values containing jinja2 template expressions and starting with "{{" **MUST** be enclosed in quotes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#hey-wait-a-yaml-gotcha).

**Good practice**: Enclose any string containing jinja2 template expression in quotes.

=>

```
        src: "{{ home }}/roles/my_role/templates/DIR1/PATH1/file1"
        dest: "{{ home }}/roles/my_role/templates/DIR1/PATH1/file2"
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. Good learning that i should use /path/file in quotes..

Comment: The issue is not with the path itself but with the templated var `{{ home }}` at start of your string.

Comment: except when using `when: `

Comment: @KevinC, `when`, `failed_when`, `changed_when`, should not contain any templating expression (you will get a warning if they do). Hence there should never be a `{{` starting the string so you should never get into this situation.